# Minusing While- Loop

Tags: java

The Scanner is not minusing euros:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Luottolaskuri {

    private static Scanner lukija;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lukija = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Anna luotollisen ostoksen hinta: ");
        double loh = lukija.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Anna kuukausierien lukumäärä: ");
        int kkelkm = lukija.nextInt();
        int counter = 1;
        while (counter < 7) {
            double lasku = loh / kkelkm;
            double viimlasku = loh - lasku;
            DecimalFormat kaksiDesimaalia = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
              String muotoiltu = kaksiDesimaalia.format(lasku);
              String muotoiltu2 = kaksiDesimaalia.format(viimlasku);
            System.out.println(counter + ". erä "+ muotoiltu +" euroa, luottoa jäljellä " + muotoiltu2 + " euroa");
            counter++;
            viimlasku--;
        }

    }

}
```

Should look like this:

```
Anna luotollisen ostoksen hinta: 500,0
Anna kuukausierien lukumäärä: 4
1. erä 125,00 euroa, luottoa jäljellä 375,00 euroa
2. erä 125,00 euroa, luottoa jäljellä 250,00 euroa
3. erä 125,00 euroa, luottoa jäljellä 125,00 euroa
4. erä 125,00 euroa, luottoa jäljellä **0,00** euroa
```

But mine looks like this :

```
Anna luotollisen ostoksen hinta: 500,0
Anna kuukausierien lukumäärä: 4
1. erä 125,00 euroa, luottoa jäljellä 375,00 euroa
2. erä 125,00 euroa, luottoa jäljellä 375,00 euroa
3. erä 125,00 euroa, luottoa jäljellä 375,00 euroa
4. erä 125,00 euroa, luottoa jäljellä 375,00 euroa
5. erä 125,00 euroa, luottoa jäljellä 375,00 euroa
6. erä 125,00 euroa, luottoa jäljellä **375,00** euroa
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `double viimlasku = loh - lasku;` the value of `loh` never changes, so `viimlasku` gets the same value in each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented the changed lines:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Luottolaskuri {

    private static Scanner lukija;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        lukija = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Anna luotollisen ostoksen hinta: ");
        double loh = lukija.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Anna kuukausierien lukumäärä: ");
        int kkelkm = lukija.nextInt();
        int counter = 1;
        double lasku = loh / kkelkm; // initialize outside the loop
        double viimlasku = loh; // initial value
        while (counter <= kkelkm) { // use # of iterations, not a hardcoded value
            viimlasku -= lasku; // substract
            DecimalFormat kaksiDesimaalia = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
              String muotoiltu = kaksiDesimaalia.format(lasku);
              String muotoiltu2 = kaksiDesimaalia.format(viimlasku);
            System.out.println(counter + ". erä "+ muotoiltu +" euroa, luottoa jäljellä " + muotoiltu2 + " euroa");
            counter++;
        }

    }

}
```